# Pandas Timeseries aggregation at multiple level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has monthly counts at various hierarchical levels. It is in long format, and I want to convert to wide format, with aggregation.

```
It is of the following format:
date | country | state | population | Vitals
01-01| cc1     | s1    | 5  |  20 
01-01| cc1     | s2    | 4  |  20
01-01| cc2    | s3    | 10 | 35
01-01| cc2     | s4   | 11 | 35
01-01| cc3    | s5    | 12 | 20
01-01| cc3     | s6    | 12 | 20
02-01| cc1     | s1    | 6 | 25 
02-01| cc1     | s2    | 5 | 25
02-01| cc2    | s3     | 11 | 40
02-01| cc2    | s4     | 12 |40
02-01| cc3    | s5     | 11 | 40
02-01| cc3    | s6     | 12 |40


I want to transform this into the following format:
date | population | vital sums
01-01| 54         | 75
02-01| 57         | 105
```

*Basically, population is summed (while grouped over time).
Vitals are grouped over date and country and then summed **for unique countries**.
Any way to do such aggregation?*

Edit: Can this be done by .agg()

Comment: Added another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum` for `population`, then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), again `sum` and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
s1 = df.groupby('date')['population'].sum()
s2 = df.drop_duplicates(['date','country','Vitals']).groupby('date')['Vitals'].sum()
```

If there is `MultiIndex`:

```
s1 = df.groupby('date')['population'].sum()
s2 = df.groupby(['date','country','Vitals'])['Vitals'].first().groupby('date').sum()
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
print (df)
       population  Vitals
date                     
01-01          54      75
02-01          57     105
```

EDIT:

Another solution if same values for each `date` and `country` combinations in `Vital` column with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then `sum` by first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.groupby(['date','country']).agg({'population':'sum', 'Vitals':'first'}).sum(level=0)
print (df)
       population  Vitals
date                     
01-01          54      75
02-01          57     105
```

Comment: @ML101 - Yes, it is used aggregation `sum`, only difference is removeing duplicates.